# Tensorflow returns too many predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am working on a TensorFlow CNN Model for mnist, modifying this example: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network_raw.py.

When running the testing 256 mnist images, it returns 784 predictions instead of 256. I am guessing the 784 comes from the mnist image size (28 pixels x 28 pixels = 784), however I am unclear where the axis alignment could be going wrong, if it is in fact an axis alignment issue.

Specifically I get the following error from this line in the code `correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1)`):

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [784] vs. [256]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]
```

**Where things may be going wrong**:

- My weight and bias matrix dimensions may not be aligning like I expect. I am attempting to use manually defined weights/biases, and while I think the dimensions align, I am clearly missing something.
- I may not be using the dense layer correctly. I added the dense layer to go from the weights (4x4x50x500) to the correct size for the classification layer (500x10). The image below shows debugging info and these dimensions.

  [image: Screen shot of debugging]

**Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle

input_size = 28  # e.g. 28x28 input
model = pickle.load(open("model.p", "rb" ))

weights = {
    'wc1': tf.Variable(model[0]['weights']),  # 5x5x20
    'wc2': tf.Variable(model[2]['weights']),  # 5x5x20x50
    'wd1': tf.Variable(model[4]['weights']),  # 4x4x50x500
    'out': tf.Variable(model[5]['weights'])  # 500x10
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(model[0]['bias']),  # 20
    'bc2': tf.Variable(model[2]['bias']),  # 50
    'bd1': tf.Variable(model[4]['bias']),  # 500
    'out': tf.Variable(model[5]['bias']),  # 10
    }


# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./MNIST-data/", one_hot=True)

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)  # dropout (keep probability)



# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W,strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

# Create model
def conv_net(x, weights, biases):
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, input_size, input_size, 1])
    conv1 = conv2d(x, tf.reshape(weights['wc1'], shape=[5, 5, 1, 20]), biases['bc1'])
    pool1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)
    conv2 = conv2d(pool1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    pool2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 4 * 4 * 50])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=500, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    # Output, class prediction
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(dense, weights['out']), biases['out'])  # shape = (?, 10)
    return out


logits = conv_net(X, weights, biases)
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# # Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Calculate accuracy for 256 MNIST test images
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
          sess.run(accuracy, {X: mnist.test.images[:256], Y: mnist.test.labels[:256], keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I switched to tensorflow slim and all my problems were pretty much instantaneously solved. I never figured out the issue with the above code, so this isn't technically an answer, just wanted to provide advice if anybody else has similar problems.